# Type 'ParsedData<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Asset[]': - Nest.js

Tags: node.js, csv, nestjs

Im trying to bring in https://www.npmjs.com/package/nest-csv-parser

I have set up and have the file uploading correctly and Im now facing an error

I have followed the docs and created the class for the entity

```js
class Asset {
    name: string;
    ref_number: string;
    external_ref_number: string;
    type: string;
    condition: string;
    description: string;
    notes: string;
    upload_date: string;
    expiry_date: string;
    site_id: string;

}
```

and then my controller is doing the below

```js
 @Get('import')
    async parseCSVFile()
    {
        const csvPath = getCSVFile();
        const stream = fs.createReadStream(csvPath)
        const entities: Asset[] = await this.csvParser.parse(stream, Asset)
        await this.assetService.addCSV(entities.list)
        return {
            data: {
                message: "File uploaded successfully!",
            }
        }
    }
```

and thats where I get the error
Type 'ParsedData' is missing the following properties from type 'Asset[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.

on line:

```js
const entities: Asset[] = await this.csvParser.parse(stream, Asset)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looks like their docs are incorrect](https://github.com/mCzolko/nest-csv-parser/blob/master/lib/csv.parser.ts#L8). You need to access `.list` or the `ParsedData` interface to get back the array of data you are expecting. You should be able to do something like `const { list: entities }: ParsedData<Asset> = await this.csvParser.parse(stream, Asset)` to create the `entities` constant as the `Asset[]` type like you're expecting